# Which node should I push data to in a cluster?

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka

I've setup a [kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) cluster with 3 nodes.

```
kafka01.example.com
kafka02.example.com
kafka03.example.com
```

Kafka does replication so that any node in the cluster can be removed without loosing data.

Normally I would send all data to kafka01, however that will break the entire cluster if that one node goes down.

What is industry best practice when dealing with clusters? I'm evaluating setting up an NGINX reverse proxy with round robin load balancing. Then I can point all data producers at the proxy and it will divvy up between the nodes.

I need to ensure that no data is lost if one of the nodes becomes unavailable.

- Is an nginx reverse proxy an appropriate tool for this use case?
- Is my assumption correct that a round robin reverse proxy will distribute the data and increase reliability without data loss?
- Is there a different approach that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally your producer takes care of distributing the data to all (or selected set of) nodes that are up and running by using a partitioning function either in a round robin mode or by using some semantics of your choice. The producer publishes to a partition of a topic and different nodes are leaders for different partitions of one topic. If a broker node becomes unavailable, this node will fall out of the cluster (In Sync Replicas) and new leaders for partitions on that node will be selected. Through metadata requests/responses, your producer will become aware of this fact and push messages to other nodes which are currently up.